# Get only different entries in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have got a collection in MongoDB with different files. Each file contains a filename and a version number. How can I find the latest of each files?

The documents look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("51834f42ddf4010a00000000"),
f: "test.php",
v: 1,
code: "PD8NCg0KZWNobyAnR3V0ZW4gVGFnISc7DQoNCj8+"
```

f = filename, v = version number, (code = file content)

Let's say there is one file with the name `test.php` and another one called `second_test.php`. I want to select the document with the highest versions number of each of these files.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.files.find("f" => "test.php").sort({"v" => -1}).limit(1).first()
db.files.find("f" => "second_test.php").sort({"v" => -1}).limit(1).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file names then you can do a simple find like @gtsouk shows however, if you do not know the file name you could use the aggregation framework:

```
$db->files->aggregate(array(
    array('$sort'=>array('v'=>-1)),
    array('$group' => array('_id'=>'$f', 'f_id' => array('$first'=>'$id'), 
          'v'=>array('$first'=>'$v')))    
));
```

Which will group the collection on the latest version of the file.